# TestFairy project URL not found in build output

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, testfairy

I'm getting the above error while uploading build to test fairy using the Android Studio plugin. What project URL are they talking about ?

testfairy output :

```
TestFairy project URL not found in build output
Done
```

I added the plugin following the instructions in this link :
http://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Uploading_with_Android_Studio.html

This added auto-generated code to my gradle file after taking my testfairy API key. I know the is right as I could upload the build until last week.

Here is the auto generated code bit:

```
//TestFairy start - autogenerated by TestFairy intellij plugin
//manual changes might get overwritten
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://www.testfairy.com/maven' }
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.testfairy.plugins.gradle:testfairy:1.+'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
android {
   testfairyConfig {
       apiKey 'myAPIkey'
   }
}
//TestFairy end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It happened to me when i upgraded from gradle (project level) 2.2.2 to 2.2.3. When i reverted to 2.2.2 the bug was gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation and yes you are doing as it says, to the mark. I don't have a solution but you can try to raise the issue with the testfairy team, here: https://github.com/testfairy/testfairy-android-studio-plugin/issues